# How to see the app changes on a device in real time?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

Every time I change a code even it's only one line I have to run the command

```
sudo ionic cordova prepare ios
```

and I have to click play button on Xcode to unable to upload the app on the iPhone and see the changes in action.

Basically every time I want to test the app, I am repeating this steps and each time it takes approximately 4 minutes to see if this single line of code I wrote is working or not. Is there a way to see this changes in real time?

If I run

```
sudo ionic serve
```

and if I make a change the changes are appear on the browser real time but I need to test the camera and the return key on the iPhone so browser doesn't work for me. For instance I can switch between the inputs with the "tab key" but I cannot switch between the inputs with the "return key".

Is there a way to see the changes in real time? That would save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to see the changes in real time?

Yes, there is! The answer is **[Ionic DevApp](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/devapp/)**

> The Ionic DevApp is a free app that makes it **easy to run your Ionic
>   app directly on your iOS or Android device**.
>
> Skip dealing with frustrating Native SDK installation issues, just run
>   ionic serve -c, open the DevApp, connect to the same network, and the
>   app will automatically load and run your app.
>
> The DevApp comes with many native plugins built right in, so you don’t
>   need to worry about installing plugins.

You can check the list of supported Cordova plugins **[here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/view.html#plugin-support)**.

Comment: Thank you. First time I hear this app. I believe it will solve my problem. I already have installed plugins. Do you mean that DevApp doesn't need any plugin to run the app in real time?

Comment: That's right, the plugins listed in that link should work in the DevApp just like they'd work in a physical device @hijacker83